# How can I use CSS to alter a jQuery-produced class assignment based on whether the link is visited or not?

Tags: jquery, css

We are using a regular expression to determine if a link is to an internal or external page. If the link is to an external page, a class is assigned which affixes an external page icon to the link.  Here is the regex:

```
//Identify external links
jQuery("a[href*='http://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"']),[href*='https://']:not([href*='"+location.hostname+"'])")
.addClass("external");
//Append span to display Icon
jQuery('#content1 a.external').append('<span class="external_link" />');
```

Can I use my CSS to change the icon that is applied according to whether or not the link in question has been visited? [i.e., the external link icon is a different color if the link has been visited, just like the link itself behaves]

I don't really think it can be done in CSS.  My reasoning is that the jQuery assigns the class based on what kind of link it is, regardless of whether or not the link has been visited. So there's no way to assign a pseudo-class :visited to the span class that was created by the jQuery regular expression.

But maybe someone knows a neat CSS trick that I'm not thinking of-- admittedly not hard to do at all.

My CSS for the non-visited icon (it's a sprite):

```
span.external_link { 
background: url(/hslc/global/icons/icon-external.gif) no-repeat scroll left top transparent; 
display: inline-block; 
height: 10px; 
line-height: 16px; 
margin: 0 0 0 0.25em; 
padding: 0; width: 10px; }
```

CSS for the visited version of the icon, which does *not* work:

```
a:visited span.external_link { background-position: 0 -100px }
```

This page contains an example if you'd like to see one. The link directly under the video shows an external link icon doin' its thing...  http://eclkc.ohs.acf.hhs.gov/hslc/tta-system/teaching/center/practice/ISS/zone.html

Thanks!

Using BoltClock's link in the comments, I found that background image can't be used to style visited links anymore. Color can be used.  So I used the Baron's solution below, and X + Y selector to write this:

```
span.external_link::after  { 
content:    "<- unvisited!"; 
color:      green; }  

a:visited + span.external_link::after {  
content:    "<- visited!"; 
color:      red; }
```

I am only getting green/unvisited text. I can't get red/visited to show up

I made a fiddle of this exact CSS. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  I can never get red/visited to apply.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/zLyMn/4/

Comment: It looks like stylesheets are also affected by `:visited` acting like `:link` due to privacy concerns - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: Lol what a great URL `http://eclkc.ohs.acf.hhs.gov/` very easy to memorize.

Comment: :D  Are you trying to say this doesn't just roll off your tongue?

Comment: BoltClock, this is a very useful link. It looks like I could color that icon if it was font-based and I used "color", a permitted style for visited links, instead of it being image based.  Doesn't this only apply to Firefox?  They are talking about changes to Gecko.

Comment: edited question using BoltClock's info and Baron's selector. I'm not quite there yet, can't get visited to register.

Comment: Other browsers have started to adopt some of these changes, but I'm not entirely sure of the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select that span with an adjacent selector like so:

```
a:visited + span.external_link { }
```

See here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: I think to use X + Y, both X and Y need to be elements. a:visited is a pseudo-class.

Comment: Oh, the plot thickens. I was reading @BoltClock's recommendation in the comment on the main question and saw this:  "Also, if you use a sibling connector such as :visited + span, the <span> will be styled as if the link were unvisited." which looks like pseudo-class can be used in X + Y

Comment: I'm trying to use this selector, but I can't get the visited state to respond.  Here is a fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/zLyMn/  Do you have any more advice?

Comment: The `:visited` pseudo selector is intentionally only partially functional for security reasons. Mozilla's documentation explains this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector You won't be able to style siblings of `:visited` because the browser will always lie and say the link is unvisited.

Comment: Thanks ssorallen. I was afraid of that after reading more about the security feature.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is compare some css property of your link to wether it has the style of a visited link and then adjust whatever you need to reflect this:

CSS:

```
a:visited { color: red;}
```

JS:

```
if($("a").css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 238)") {
    $("div").text("Link was visited");
}
```

Please check the fiddle:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/77ZjH/)

Comment: Well that certainly worked. I was hoping for a CSS solution. I can go back to this if a CSS-based solution can't be found.